# How to show data in stimulesoft so that every group locate in one page?

Tags: stimulsoft

I have a table that I want to show every data group in separate page.How can I do this?for example this is my query:
    select .... group by code.
and I want to show every code's information in one page.how can I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use the Group Header and set the New Page Before property of this header to True.